# Displaying the proper time in a counter timer everytime the page refreshes

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Well!I don't know If I made the title proper even..I'm making an online examination system..
I'm stuck in a page right now..
I'm having a page where I'm displaying the questions one by one i.e on click of the buttons next and previous,the respective question is displayed from the database.Above the questions,I have a timer counter which shows the remaining time for the exam.
When I go to the exam page,all works fine.1st question gets displayed and the counter starts.
The problem starts when I hit the next button(next & prev are submit buttons) for the next question,the page gets refreshed as the next ques gets displayed 'n the counter starts from the beginning again.Here is the code for displaying the questions along with the counter made in JS....

```
<?php

require_once('connect.php');
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['ta'])){
$_SESSION['ta']=0;
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['qno'])){
$_SESSION['qno']=1;
$q2=$_SESSION['qno'];

}
else{

if(isset($_POST['next'])){

    $q2=$_POST['q2'];
    $ans=$_POST['ans'];
    $_SESSION['qno']+=1;
    $reply=$_POST['question1'];
    if(isset($_POST['question1'])){

    $query="select `qno` from `answer` where `uname`='{$_SESSION['user']}'
 and `qno`='$q2'";
    $q_r=mysqli_query($con,$query);

    $n1=mysqli_num_rows($q_r);

    if($n1<1){

        $_SESSION['ta']+=1;

    }


    $query="select `qno` from `answer` where `uname`='{$_SESSION['user
and `qno`='$q2'";
    $q_r=mysqli_query($con,$query);

    $n=mysqli_num_rows($q_r);

    if($n>0){
        $new_quer="update `answer` set `reply`='$reply' where 
`uname`='{$_SESSION['user']}' and `qno`='$q2'";
        mysqli_query($con,$new_quer);

    }
    else{
        $new_q="insert into `answer`
 values('{$_SESSION['user']}',$q2,year(now()),'$ans','$reply')";
        mysqli_query($con,$new_q);
    }



    $reply="";
}
}

if(isset($_POST['previous'])){
    $_SESSION['qno']-=1;
    $query="select `reply` from `answer` where 
`uname`='{$_SESSION['user']}' and `qno`='{$_SESSION['qno']}'";
    $q_r=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q_r)){
        $reply=$row['reply'];   
    }
}


if(isset($_POST['exam_submit'])){

        $q2=$_POST['q2'];
        $ans=$_POST['ans'];
        $reply=$_POST['question1'];
        $query="select `qno` from `answer` where 
`uname`='{$_SESSION['user']}' and `qno`='$q2'";
        $q_r=mysqli_query($con,$query);

        $n=mysqli_num_rows($q_r);

        if($n>0){
            $new_quer="update `answer` set `reply`='$reply' where 
`uname`='{$_SESSION['user']}' and `qno`='$q2'";
            mysqli_query($con,$new_quer);
        }
        else{
            $all_quer="insert into `answer` 
            values('{$_SESSION['user']}',
{$_SESSION['qno']},year(now()),'$ans','$reply')";
            mysqli_query($con,$all_quer);

        }
        $new_q="insert into `answer` 
values('{$_SESSION['user']}',$q2,year(now()),'$ans','$reply')";
        mysqli_query($con,$new_q);
        header('Location:result.php');      
}
} 

$q="select * from `uquestion` where `qno`='{$_SESSION['qno']}' and 
`uname`='{$_SESSION['user']}'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$q);

if ($result) {

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

$qno = $row['qno'];
$question = $row['question'];
$op1 = $row['op1'];
$op2 = $row['op2'];
$op3 = $row['op3'];
$op4 = $row['op4'];
$answer = $row['answer'];

}
}

?>

<div id="counter">
<form name="counter" style="text-align:center;" action="result.php"
method="post">
<input type="text" name="hh" id="hh" size="5" style="margin-top:5px; 
height:25px; text-align:center; font-size:18px; 
font-weight:bold; font-family:Verdana; color:blue; text-align:center;"> 
<input type="text" name="mm" id="mm" size="5" style="margin-top:5px;
height:25px; text-align:center; font-size:18px; 
font-weight:bold; font-family:Verdana; color:green; text-align:center;"> 
<input type="text" name="ss" id="ss" size="5" style="margin-top:5px;
height:25px; text-align:center; font-size:18px; 
font-weight:bold; font-family:Verdana; color:red; text-align:center;">
<br>   </form> </div>
<span style="margin-left: 39.7%; font-family:Verdana; font-weight:bold;
font-size:17px; color:blue">  
Hour </span> 
<span style="margin-left: 3.3%; font-family:Verdana; font-weight:bold; 
font-size:17px; color:green;">  
Minute </span>
<span style="margin-left:2.1%; text-align:center; font-family:Verdana;
font-weight:bold; font-size:17px; color:red;">  
Second </span>

<div style="margin-top:13px; background:-moz-linear-
gradient(top,white,#FCF,#E6E6E6,#FFF8DC); 
width:50%; margin-left:22%; padding-top:11px; padding-bottom:12px; 
padding-left:2%;">

<form name="exam" method="post" action="exam.php">
<input type="hidden" name="ans" value="<?php echo $answer; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="q2" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['qno']; ?>">
 <table width="100%" cellpadding="5">
<tr> <td style="border-bottom:2px solid blue; font-size:15px; color:blue; 
font-weight:bold;
text-shadow:rgba(160,160,200,0.5) 5px 6px 4px; font-family:Verdana;">
Question : </td> </tr>
<tr> <td style="font-size:16px; color:red; font-weight:bold; 
text-shadow:rgba(200,160,170,0.6) 6px 7px 4px;
font-family:verdana;"> 
<?php echo $question ?> </td> </tr>

<tr> <td style="text-shadow:rgba(160,200,270,0.5) 5px 6px 4px; 
font-size:14px; color:green; font-weight:bold;
font-family:verdana;">

<input type="radio" name="question1" id="q1" value="op1" <?php    
if($reply=="op1"){ echo 'checked="checked"';}

 ?> />
<?php echo $op1; ?></td> </tr>
<tr> <td style="text-shadow:rgba(160,200,270,0.5) 5px 6px 4px; 
font-size:14px; color:green; font-weight:bold;
font-family:verdana;">
<input type="radio" name="question1" id="q2" value="op2" <?php 
if($reply=="op2"){ echo 'checked="checked"';}?> /> 
<?php echo $op2;  ?> </td> </tr>
<tr> <td style="text-shadow:rgba(160,200,170,0.5) 5px 6px 4px; 
font-size:14px; color:green; font-weight:bold;
font-family:verdana;">
<input type="radio" name="question1" id="q3" value="op3" <?php 
if($reply=="op3"){ echo 'checked="checked"';}?> /> 
<?php echo $op3;  ?> </td> </tr>
<tr> <td style="text-shadow:rgba(160,200,170,0.5) 5px 6px 4px; 
font-size:14px; color:green; font-weight:bold;
font-family:verdana;">
<input type="radio" name="question1" id="q4" value="op4" <?php 
if($reply=="op4"){ echo 'checked="checked"';}?> /> 
<?php echo $op4;  ?> </td> </tr>
<tr> <td>
<input type="submit" name="previous" value="Previous" style="width:16%; 
 height:30px;" <?php if($qno==1)
 echo 'disabled="disabled"'?>>
 <input type="submit" name="next" value="Next" style="width:16%; 
height:30px;" <?php if($qno==5)
echo 'disabled="disabled"'?>>  </td> </tr>

<tr> <td style="text-shadow:rgba(160,160,200,0.5) 4px 5px 4px; 
font-size:12px; color:#03F; font-weight:bold;
font-family:verdana; border-top:2px solid blue;"> Question <?php 
echo $qno; ?> of 10 </td> </tr>
<tr> <td style="text-shadow:rgba(160,160,200,0.5) 4px 5px 4px;
font-size:12px; color:#03F; font-weight:bold;
font-family:verdana;"> Total Attempted : <?php echo $_SESSION['ta']; ?> 
</td> </tr>

<tr> <td>
<input type="submit" name="exam_submit" value="I'm done!Submit Test"
onclick="return confirm('Are you Sure?')"
style="width:97%; height:37px; background:green;
color:white; font-family:Verdana; font-size:15px; font-weight:bold;">
  </td> </tr> 
 </table>
</form>

<script language="javascript">

var sec=0; 
var mins=1; 
document.counter.hh.value=00;
document.counter.mm.value=mins;
document.counter.ss.value=sec;
function display(){
if(document.counter.mm.value=="00" &&  document.counter.ss.value=="00"){
    document.counter.submit();
}

if (sec<=0){ 
sec=60 
mins-=1 
} 
if (mins<=-1){ 
sec=0 
mins+=1 
} 
else 
sec-=1

if(sec<10){
sec=sec*1;
sec='0'+sec;
}
if(mins<10){
mins=mins*1;
mins='0'+mins;
}

document.counter.mm.value=mins;
document.counter.ss.value=sec;

setTimeout("display()",1000)

}

display();

</script>
</div>
```

Please suggest how to deal with it.Your help is really really appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry @RohitSharma, I misunderstood your question. Now I have reformulated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143322/displaying-the-proper-time-in-a-counter-timer-everytime-the-page-refreshes/30143644#30143644). This is tested and works perfectly, let me know if it fits your request! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use only seconds for a counter so it is easier to manage, anyway I have made this which fits your `JavaScript` code.

First add an hidden field in your **exam**-named form and give it a value with `PHP`:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["howMuchTime"]) && $_POST["howMuchTime"] > 0) {
    $hmt = $_POST["howMuchTime"];
}
else { $hmt = 0;}
?>
<input type="hidden" name="howMuchTime" value="<?php echo $hmt; ?>" />
```

Then, in your `JavaScript` code declare the following vars:

```
var totalTime = 450; // 7 minutes and 30 seconds
var hmt = document.exam.howMuchTime.value: // Keeps track of how much time is elapsed from the examination start
var timer = totalTime - hmt;
```

And change your **hours-mins-seconds** vars like this:

```
var hours = parseInt(timer / 3600); // Changes the "timer" var in hours
var mins = parseInt((timer - (hours * 3600)) / 60); //Changes the "timer" var in minutes
var sec = timer - (hours * 3600) - (mins * 60); // Changes the "timer" var in seconds
// And then the counter hh-mm-ss displayed
document.counter.hh.value = hours;
document.counter.mm.value = mins;
document.counter.ss.value = sec;
```

Change the condition in your first `if` statement in your `display()` function:

```
if(document.counter.hh.value == "00" && document.counter.mm.value == "00" && document.counter.ss.value == "00")
```

And add this in your `display()` function:

```
if(hours < 10) {
    // Add the first 0 to the "hours" value like you have done for minutes and seconds
    hours = hours * 1;
    hours = '0' + hours;
}
```

Then update the **hours** value too each time the function is executed:

```
document.counter.hh.value = hours;
```

And in the `display()` function update the **howMuchTime** counter you created (hidden input) in your **exam**-named form:

```
document.exam.howMuchTime.value++;
```

This is tested and works perfectly.

Comment: Yo Buddy!that's worked.Thank you..Sorry for late response though.. ;)

Comment: I'm having another problem now.It aint counter related anyway.

Comment: Say,a user choose to take an exam,He clicks the link n the exam starts with the 1st question being displayed.

Comment: Now let's say We prvided 10 ques 'n the user answers q1,q2...so on up to q10,suddenly he remembers his q1 ans is incorrect so he comes back to q1 by hitting the previous btn till q1 appears,now he modifies his ans for q1 then hit next btn.The problem starts here,all the ans he did from q2-q9 get erased.So how to make the answers remain as he answerd them no matter how much time the page is refreshed for clicking the btns Next n Prev;hve done it for Previos btn i.e the ans dsn't get erased on clicking the Prev btn.But the same logic doesn;t work for Next.Hope u'd help n provde me da code fo ds.

Comment: @RohitSharma, I'm glad to be of help, remember to mark the answer as accepted. **;)** Unfortunately this is too long to explain here, [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and provide all the code you have tried so far for your problem so it can have mor visibility.

Comment: I have a facebook account but I don't use it too much XD Can I know why?

Comment: So that I get lill more help from you completing this damn project..please provide me the link to your Facebook account... Thanks..

Comment: bro are you there..??

Comment: Hey sorry man, I'm messed up between projects to finish, and customers who do not pay and I completely forgot about you, sorry. I suggest you keep on asking on this site that is full of excellent programmers even better than me. Although I use this site sporadically, I'll keep an eye on your account to see if I can answer your questions, but remember that 4 million of minds are better than one! **;)**

Comment: I posted one..but sadly nobody could answer.. :D may be they didn't understand what I was trying to express..i think u only can understand it very clearly since u once dealt with my codes.. Bro please add me here www.facebook.com/rohit4dj

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the counter on the server side probably using sessions.

Here is how you can do it.

```
$_SESSION['startTime'] = time();
```

Then using javascript on each page you can the run the countdown timer using the session variable as starting point and when user clicks a button, you can update the value of countdown timer using:

```
 $currentTime = time() - $_SESSION['startTime'];
```